# Transcluding without running digest on contents (passing raw HTML) in Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass raw HTML inside a directive for later transclusion (when I open a modal - I will use the HTML to populate it)

The problem is - that if I do it like this, the contents of dialog-body get run and the ng-repeat is implemented, which means when I pass the template along, it gets run again causing an *ahem* stack overflow.

Is there a way for me to use transclusion or something else to pass the inner HTML without running any digest on it?

```
<dialog-body>
    <div ng-repeat="item_value in item.values">
        {{item_value.string}}
    </div>                     
</dialog-body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I figured out how to get this done.
Angular was running `ng-repeat` on the initial code, then re-running it once I used it later on. To avoid this - I did this to skip the first ng-repeat run:

```
<dialog-body ng-non-bindable>
    <div ng-repeat="item_value in item.values">
        {{item_value.string}}
    </div>                     
</dialog-body>
```

This meant that I was only passing the actual HTML and not running Angular on it. I then used a `querySelector` to find all the `ng-non-bindable` attributes and remove them. Seems to work fine.

Hope this helps someone!